# Updated_at in Ecto after Repo.update_all

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to update my `Asset` table so I need to do something like this.

```
from(a in Asset, 
where: a.id == ^asset.id, 
update: [set: [asset_name: "a name"] ]
)
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

This works fine however the `updated_at` is not updating.

from the documentation:

> Keep in mind this update_all will not update autogenerated fields like
>   the updated_at columns.

So does this mean, I need to pass the time into my query? something like `DateTime.utc_now`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to automatically update the timestamp so it should be something like:

```
Asset
|> where([a], a.id == ^asset.id)
|> update([set: [asset_name: "a name", updated_at: Timex.now()]])
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

I use `Timex.now()` here but I guess `DateTime.utc_now()` will work just as fine but I have not tested it.

If you do that often, I would probably create a generic function that accepts a query and adds the timestamp update to it and returns the updated query.

Comment: Cool. I am using `NaiveDateTime.utc_now()`. Cheers

Comment: @MrH `timex` is just a library that I use instead of the native dates and thats why I wasn't sure how to achieve it without it but glad that `NaiveDateTime.utc_now()` worked :)